# How to know what Spring dependency I should add to my Maven project to get the function I need?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to define what functions ginve Spring maven dependencies.

Is there a table with list of all Spring dependencies and their hierarchy and description?

P. S. 
Using Spring 4+

Comment: You can find the dependencies of a mvn artifact on http://mvnrepository.com/ - what functionality are you looking for?

Comment: @reto, I want to know, e. g. what dependencies should I add to my project  to build a spring mvc application. Or to use only spring dependency injection. Or smth else.

Comment: Well, any proper manual for e.g. Spring MVC, DI, etc. will list the maven dependencies that are required. What is your concrete question?

Comment: is this helpful ? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html

Comment: @OhadR, great! Thank you! If you write this as an answer I could check it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might be helpfull (Spring Docs):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html

Have a look at [section 2.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules), they describe each module and what it consists of.